# Xubuntu Thunar Menu Bar disabled, now lost forever

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

I have been using Xubuntu (latest version 14) for quite a while, and I love it.

However, recently I was using the Thunar File Manager, and decided to see what it looks like with a little more real estate by disabling the top Menu Bar in the Views function. Well, Thunar did what I asked it to.

But now without a Menu Bar, I have no way of getting back to the View menu to re-activate the Menu Bar.

I tried Alt-V and Alt-Shift-V, but nothing happens.

HELP! How do I get my Menu Bar back?

Answer (score 43):

The shortcut for disabling and enabling the menu bar in my German version is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Try that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I tried Ctrl-M, Ctrl-Shift-M, Alt-M, and Alt-Shift-M to no avail. I thought that the standard short-cut key was Alt + (underlined_letter) on Menu Bar. So that would be Alt-V. For example, if I type Alt-V on Firefox, the View Menu drops down. But this feature doesn't seem to be implemented in Thunar. Oh, well .. back to the drawing board. BTW - This is interesting ... when I run Nautilus from Alt-F2 (Application Finder), the top Menu Bar is ALSO missing! And on Nautilus, I never touched any settings. Weird ... Anyway, thanks. Ray.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks @Minix! Sorry it didn't work for OP.

Comment: works in thunar 1.6.1

Comment: This works for the English version

Comment: Thanks for the tip! They should account for people pressing `Ctrl+M` by mistake and wondering where the menu suddenly disappeared!

Answer (score 8):

Use <kbd>F10</kbd> key to open or temporarily show the menu bar in Thunar.

The shortcut key behaves differently depending on menu bar visibility:

- If menu bar in Thunar is *visible*, press <kbd>F10</kbd> key *once* to open menu in menu bar.
- If menu bar in Thunar is *hidden*, press <kbd>F10</kbd> key *twice* to temporarily show and open menu in menu bar (same result as visible).

To make the menu bar always visible again:

1. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> key twice
2. Use cursor keys to navigate to **View** > **Menubar** (Press right-cursor key twice, then press down-cursor key five times)
3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> key to select that menu
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to close the menu

The menu shortcut key is applicable to GTK+ applications including Thunar. Unlike the combination key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, the function key <kbd>F10</kbd> will work as it is regardless of keyboard layout.

Comment: i couldn't get this to work for the terminal window — it interprets the f10 keystroke as a tilde input for the command line

Comment: i just discovered if i right-click the *terminal contents,* "show menubar" is listed as an option — this is *not* the case when i right-click the "window chrome" around the contents such as the icon and titlebar

Comment: I have at least clarified that Xfce Terminal in 18.04 works as expected even when menubar is hidden. Terminal window may not work properly in older releases. Otherwise, [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`xfce4-settings-editor` is your friend.

- Close all thunar windows
- start `xfce4-settings-editor` from the console
- locate `thunar` on the left hand tab
- check `last-menubar-visible`
- open a new thunar window

done.

Bonus:

- memorize the shortcut key for your locale :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I did try the Settings Manager from the XFCE Menu a couple days ago (didn't need to start it from the console), but I didn't see any "left hand tab", or anything that said Thunar on it. So today I spent some more time fishing around for a solution, and I found a similar problem posted. The solution was to run from console: "xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /last-menubar-visible -s true". After I did that, when I loaded Thunar again, I had my menu bar back. I came to this page to inform everyone of the solution, but you beat me too it! Thanks again. Ray.

Comment: BTW ... The hot key to display the Menu Bar on Thunar in my locale (America) is Ctrl-M. But for some reason, when Aibara Iduas advised me to try that, it did NOT work. Nothing at all happened, and I tried Ctrl-M and Ctrl-Shift-M several times (when the property was set to false). But now it is working. Weird. Thanks again, Ray.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

I find it trying every shortcut I could think. May that be helpful!